# In Objective C, what is the syntax for creating a method with unlimited parameters like NSLog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to write an Objective-C method whose input is an array of strings and whose output is that list of strings concatenated, but only those which are not nil.

Any ideas if this function is already somewhere in the foundation?

If it's not already done, how can I write a method which has an unlimited number of NSString parameters?  For instance, like the params keyword in C# which will essentially convert the params list into an array.

thanks

Comment: Are you talking variadic methods in Objective C? If so, just google up. Plenty of examples

Comment: Infact I guess the exact solution to what you are trying to achieve is in that link I posted as my asnwer. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `...` (ellipsis):

```
- yourMessage:arg1, ...;
```

[Here's official Apple information on the subject.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2005/qa1405.html)

Here I am copying their sample:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...;  // This method takes a nil-terminated list of objects.

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
id eachObject;
va_list argumentList;
if (firstObject)                      // The first argument isn't part of the varargs list,
  {                                   // so we'll handle it separately.
  [self addObject: firstObject];
  va_start(argumentList, firstObject);          // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.
  while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
    [self addObject: eachObject];               // that isn't nil, add it to self's contents.
  va_end(argumentList);
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I did all work but it was not working so I reset all my work and now I see 'nil terminated' mentioned in comments. Error was because i didn' terminated the list by nil. Just stating that it might help.

Comment: How would this work with static methods, like on NSLog?

Answer (score 2):

[Variable arguments in Objective-C methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2005/qa1405.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer might just be in this nice post.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html